# CefSharp Support Flash Plugin,But in the load pop-up DOS window

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I User CefSharp

code:

```
var setting = new CefSharp.CefSettings();
setting.CefCommandLineArgs["ppapi-flash-path"] = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll";
CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(setting);
```

Run time:

[image]

I want to know why it appears, how not to let the other pop up

CefSharp Version # CefSharp 47.0.0.0   libcef.dll 3.2526.1362.0

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the `Pepper Flash` plugin being run without `Sandbox`, unfortunately there is no workaround and the `upstream` issue has been marked as `WONTFIX`.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=508002